# how to embed image in body using commons mail 1.3

Tags: java, html, email, sendmail, apache-commons

here is my code which attach and send image but i want to load image form local drive and embed it to body of mail without attaching please help me i have searched still no solution.
thanks
    import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
    import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
    import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;

```
public class img {

     public static void main(String[]args)  throws Exception {


         // Create the attachment
          EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
          attachment.setPath("Monthly Target AchivedDaily.gif");
          attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.INLINE);
          attachment.setDescription("Monthly");
          attachment.setName("1");


            HtmlEmail he = new HtmlEmail();




               he.setSmtpPort(25);
              he.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myid","mypwd"));

              he.setDebug(false);
              he.setHostName("..com");
              he.addTo("@.com","hsn");

                //email.setSSL(true);
              he.setFrom("mail", "Hassan");
              he.setSubject("tst1");
              he.attach(attachment);




              he.send();

            System.out.println("Done...");







     }





}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used this facility, but after a little research: [here's](http://www.codereye.com/2009/08/sending-html-email-with-embedded-images.html) a link to some examples. Also, see the docs for `org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail.embed(String url, String name)`[2](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/commons-email/commons-email/1.0/commons-email-1.0-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html#embed%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29)

You'd make a call like

```
String id = email.embed(new URL("file://localhost/home/mydir/images/my_image.png"), "My image");
```

Comment: thanks it works but i have to add cid after that i can embed image :)

Comment: Please note that commons-email comes with support for automatically resolving these URLs, even when the images reside on a local folder, so you don't need to do that manually. Look at the test-cases at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/email/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/mail/ImageHtmlEmailTest.java?view=markup for details